# how to export raw XML returned from Invoke-RestRequest with Export-CliXml?

Tags: xml, powershell, exist-db, export-to-xml, invoke-restmethod

How can I get the `curl` result of just `<notes/>`, from `eXist`, with `PowerShell`?

```
PS /home/nicholas> 
PS /home/nicholas> $url='http://localhost:8080/exist/rest/db/scripts/notes.xq'
PS /home/nicholas> 
PS /home/nicholas> $url                                                       
http://localhost:8080/exist/rest/db/scripts/notes.xq
PS /home/nicholas> 
PS /home/nicholas> $result=Invoke-RestMethod -Method Get -Uri $url -Headers @{"Content-Type" = "text/xml"}
PS /home/nicholas> 
PS /home/nicholas> $result

notes
-----


PS /home/nicholas> 
PS /home/nicholas> $result | Export-Clixml ./result.xml
PS /home/nicholas> 
PS /home/nicholas> Get-Content ./result.xml                                                               
<Objs Version="1.1.0.1" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/powershell/2004/04">
  <Obj RefId="0">
    <XD>&lt;notes /&gt;</XD>
  </Obj>
</Objs>
PS /home/nicholas> 
PS /home/nicholas> exit
nicholas@mordor:~$ 
nicholas@mordor:~$ curl http://localhost:8080/exist/rest/db/scripts/notes.xq
<notes/>nicholas@mordor:~$ 
nicholas@mordor:~$
```

and why does the above `XML` have an `XD` tag, and to what end?

The help file states:

> DESCRIPTION
>
> The `Export-Clixml` cmdlet creates a Common Language Infrastructure
> (CLI) XML-based representation of an object or objects and stores it
> in a file. You can then use the `Import-Clixml` cmdlet to recreate the
> saved object based on the contents of that file. For more information
> about CLI, see Language independence
> (/dotnet/standard/language-independence).
>
> ```
> This cmdlet is similar to `ConvertTo-Xml`, except that `Export-Clixml` stores the resulting XML in a file. `ConvertTo-XML` 
> returns the XML, so you can continue to process it in PowerShell.
>
> A valuable use of `Export-Clixml` on Windows computers is to export credentials and secure strings securely as XML. For an 
> example, see Example 3.
> ```

Answer (score 0):

invoking `OuterXml` works:

```
PS /home/nicholas> 
PS /home/nicholas> $url                                                                                   
http://localhost:8080/exist/rest/db/scripts/notes.xq
PS /home/nicholas> 
PS /home/nicholas> $result=Invoke-RestMethod -Method Get -Uri $url -Headers @{"Content-Type" = "text/xml"}
PS /home/nicholas> 
PS /home/nicholas> $result.OuterXml                                                                       
<notes />
PS /home/nicholas> 
PS /home/nicholas> ($result | ConvertTo-Xml).OuterXml                                                     
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><Objects><Object Type="System.Xml.XmlDocument">System.Xml.XmlDocument</Object></Objects>
PS /home/nicholas>
```

but how do you check that it's `XML` at all?  or, even well-formed?